# How do you import macros in submodules in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have the following directory structure

- `/main.rs`
- `/lib.rs`
- `/tutorial/mod.rs`
- `/tutorial/foo.rs`

In `foo.rs` I need to use a macro from the glium library, `implement_vertex!`. If I put `#[macro_use] extern crate glium;` at the head of `foo.rs`, I get a `` error: an `extern crate` loading macros must be at the crate root ``. I also get a `error: macro undefined: 'implement_vertex!'`

There is also a `lib.rs` that is the crate root of the tutorial modules. I needed to put `#[macro_use]` there. Does this create 2 crate roots if I have both `main.rs` and `lib.rs`?

What is the correct way to import macros in a submodule?

Comment: Without actual code, this can only be solved by blind guessing.  All we need is the structure, where it's being imported, and where it's being used.

Comment: How do you compile (`cargo build`)? Have you modified your `Cargo.toml`? In what file is the line `mod tutorial;`? In what file is the line `mod foo;`? Without this information, we can only guess how your module tree looks like, as @DK. already said.

Answer (score 24):

Macros are handled early enough in the compilation stage that **order matters**. You, like I, probably were getting nice and used to Rust magicking away the need to care about the order of your use and crate statements.

Move your `#[macro_use] extern crate glium;` statement to the top of your `lib.rs` and/or `main.rs` file as needed.

Answer (score 11):

Do it just like the compiler told you:

> `` an `extern crate` loading macros must be at the crate root ``

Put the `#[macro_use] extern crate glium;` in the crate root, which is `main.rs` in your case. Make sure the `extern crate` statement is before your `mod` statements, otherwise the modules won't be able to access the imported macros.

You can then use the macro in your submodule.

Comment: yeah, that's the first thing I tried. It didn't work. I still get error: macro undefined: 'implement_vertex!'

Comment: Make sure the `extern crate` statement is before your `mod` statements, otherwise the mods won't be able to access the imported macros.

Comment: I'm getting the same error but for `tests/common.rs`. So what is analogous to `src/main.rs` or `src/lib.rs` for the `test` directory?

Comment: @Nawaz curios to know how did you solve this issue incase of tests directory?

Comment: @VijaySali Usually, every `.rs` file in `tests/` is compiled as its own little binary crate with your main library as dependency. So you would have to add the `#[macro_use] extern crate glium;` at the top of every file. If you add your tests manually in `Cargo.toml` via `[[test]]`, then those are you crate roots.

Comment: @VijaySali: As Lukas explained in the comment above, the solution is to add `extern crate stuff;` to each of your `tests/<each-file>.rs`. Also, note that if you want to defined a common set of functions to be used in each of your tests file, then dont define that common file as `tests/common.rs` as that'll be considered yet another _test_ file instead by `Cargo`. Define `tests/common/mod.rs` instead. Then you can add `extern crate common` to your test files.

Comment: "Make sure the extern crate statement is before your mod statements ..." actually did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I figured out my original problem. It turns out there are 2 Cargo roots? I have both a `lib.rs` and a `main.rs`. It turns out the correct place to put the `#[macro_use]` was in `lib.rs`.

Comment: Thanks - this helped me out too trying to import riker-testkit
Putting this comment here for others:
Drop this in your lib.rs:
`
#[macro_use] \n
extern crate riker_testkit;
`